# How to get all set-cookie headers from node-fetch?

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

In one of the projects I started to work on the original owner uses node-fetch for http request. node-fetch provides `res.headers.get('set-cookie')` but it only returns one of the set-cookie headers. (Usually you can have multiple set-cookie in a response header).

Without abandoning node-fetch, is it possible to get all `set-cookie` headers from the response?

Answer (score 3):

`res.headers.raw()` returns a map of header names to *arrays* of header values; so something like:

```
res.headers.raw()['set-cookie'].each(c => console.log(c))
```

Will do the trick, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers) object has a `get` method that returns an Array.

You must be using an older version of `node-fetch`. In 2.x, `res.headers.get` [should be compliant with the spec](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/master/docs/CHANGELOG.md#headers-class).

```
res.headers.get('set-cookie'); // Array
```

If you can't upgrade to 2.x for some reason, you can use the non-standard `getAll` method instead.