# Is there any way to get cookies from response with fetch in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

Is there a method to fetch the response cookies with fetch? For instance, in python there is

```
session = requests.session();
session.cookies;
```

Is there anything similar to this using fetch?

Comment: maybe: `fetch(url).then(r => console.log(r.headers.get('set-cookie')));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all set-cookie headers from node-fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53826792/how-to-get-all-set-cookie-headers-from-node-fetch)